# How to fill a vector of struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have the following code, where i defined a vector of vector of struct

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int index;
    double value;
};

int main()
{

    vector  < vector <node> >vett1;

    node p;
    p.index=5;
    p.value=2;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        vett1[i].push_back(p);

    return 0;
}
```

i don't know the right way to fill it. In this way when i run it, compilers gives me segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access `vett1[i]`, but the `vett1` has not been filled with size zero. That's why the segmentation fault error occur.

Three ways to fix it:

1. Add

   ```
   vett1.resize(10);
   ```

   before the `for` loop.
2. Or define `vett1` and set its size as follows:

   ```
   vector <vector <node>> vett1(10);
   ```
3. Or you can do this if you don't know the exact size pre-hand:

   ```
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       vector<node> temp;
       temp.push_back(p);
       vett1.push_back(temp);
   }
   ```

Comment: what if i don't know the exact size of the vector? and i want to fill it in the same way as push_back method?